# XPM - Selected Component has no available Component Template

Tags: experience-manager, sdl-tridion

XPM - Selected Component has no available Component Template error is showing when clicking Insert Button.

Content Type is added to Publication and inline edit's Content Type mapping is also added.

Drag-and-Drop on XPM is working well. Any idea why Insert button not working?

[image]

[image]

Comment: well, it looks like its content problem. Have you checked that template is allowed on a page? Does template has Shema added in allowed schemas?

Comment: yes, Drap-and-Drop on XPM is working well

Comment: Which version of Tridion and which hotfixes for XPM do you have installed?

Comment: Web 8.5, hotfix not installed